# jQuery panelSnap can't get it working

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am trying to implement the jQuery panelSnap into my website but I can't even get the demo functioning...

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, I tried fiddling around a bit but it did not help me.

This is my html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.panelSnap.js"></script>
    <script>
      var options = {
        $menu: $('header .menu')
      };

      $('.panel_container').panelSnap(options);
    </script>

    <style>
        section {
            margin-bottom:800px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#first" data-panel="first">First</a>
        <a href="#second" data-panel="second">Second</a>
        <a href="#third" data-panel="third">Third</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="panel_container">
      <section data-panel="first"><h1>test</h1><br><br>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat erat at rhoncus porta. Vestibulum fringilla viverra laoreet. Ut vel nunc adipiscing, consequat mauris eget, aliquet leo. Nunc viverra posuere elit, ut hendrerit massa dignissim vitae. Ut euismod quam ut sapien sagittis, ac euismod libero rutrum. Sed at justo felis. Proin condimentum tortor a erat laoreet, quis adipiscing velit elementum. Pellentesque egestas sem a ante aliquet, in semper eros venenatis. Mauris faucibus orci bibendum libero aliquam rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc fermentum dolor vel nisi rhoncus, ultrices tincidunt nisi vehicula. Nulla eros nibh, interdum quis tellus nec, convallis ullamcorper sapien. Pellentesque adipiscing gravida suscipit.

Proin vitae nisi quis lectus tristique auctor. Nam tristique sapien sit amet odio faucibus adipiscing. Sed lacinia tortor in mollis auctor. Proin sit amet est ante. Sed fermentum arcu ut arcu ultricies, quis luctus odio vehicula. Duis tincidunt elementum lacus quis cursus. Integer porta sit amet purus et viverra. Nulla quis sollicitudin urna. Pellentesque et nunc semper, dapibus massa ac, scelerisque ipsum. In tempus massa et tortor mattis, sit amet laoreet neque accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce euismod non massa at sagittis.

Vestibulum pulvinar purus odio. Vestibulum non iaculis metus. Maecenas at aliquam leo, eu commodo dui. In id ullamcorper metus, in convallis massa. Donec a ante nec risus vehicula suscipit sit amet a dui. Etiam quam enim, posuere et tempor vitae, accumsan vel risus. Vivamus a arcu tortor. Morbi auctor placerat massa convallis sagittis. Vivamus accumsan vulputate rhoncus. Phasellus mattis orci non luctus interdum. Praesent eu feugiat mi. Phasellus vitae elementum nunc. Aliquam luctus aliquam tellus, quis commodo ipsum molestie vel. Cras ut dignissim erat.

Aenean luctus porta enim eu feugiat. Mauris quis tristique massa, id commodo risus. Morbi consectetur, magna nec molestie tincidunt, libero nunc volutpat nulla, quis feugiat metus leo quis enim. Proin varius, turpis id rhoncus mattis, dui magna fringilla nisi, nec blandit nisl arcu ac tortor. Proin est nisi, tempor sit amet porta ac, cursus sit amet est. Praesent suscipit, nibh non malesuada aliquet, dui turpis sagittis magna, nec facilisis metus magna ut turpis. Fusce sit amet massa at mi euismod elementum sit amet id massa. Duis nec magna vitae arcu consequat tempus. Etiam non pellentesque libero. Cras aliquet convallis adipiscing. Aliquam dictum viverra sem nec tempus. Nulla odio justo, ornare ut velit vel, commodo venenatis libero. Curabitur in tincidunt elit. Ut ac luctus risus, quis interdum neque. Sed quis nulla id erat gravida pretium sit amet eget odio.

Curabitur egestas a mi eget sollicitudin. Ut interdum dictum augue lobortis consequat. Aliquam congue pharetra rhoncus. Ut nec tortor eget nunc vestibulum venenatis id quis nibh. Nullam at dui consequat, aliquet odio porttitor, convallis sapien. In bibendum ipsum non elementum euismod. Maecenas eu justo a diam mollis placerat ac sit amet mauris. Phasellus id aliquam ligula, et tristique est. Etiam at arcu pretium, accumsan odio eu, vestibulum tellus. Etiam dapibus laoreet volutpat. Sed et urna ipsum. Nulla ultrices quam sem, eu eleifend purus iaculis a. Nunc sit amet congue mauris.
      </section>
      <section data-panel="second"><h1>test</h1><br><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat erat at rhoncus porta. Vestibulum fringilla viverra laoreet. Ut vel nunc adipiscing, consequat mauris eget, aliquet leo. Nunc viverra posuere elit, ut hendrerit massa dignissim vitae. Ut euismod quam ut sapien sagittis, ac euismod libero rutrum. Sed at justo felis. Proin condimentum tortor a erat laoreet, quis adipiscing velit elementum. Pellentesque egestas sem a ante aliquet, in semper eros venenatis. Mauris faucibus orci bibendum libero aliquam rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc fermentum dolor vel nisi rhoncus, ultrices tincidunt nisi vehicula. Nulla eros nibh, interdum quis tellus nec, convallis ullamcorper sapien. Pellentesque adipiscing gravida suscipit.

Proin vitae nisi quis lectus tristique auctor. Nam tristique sapien sit amet odio faucibus adipiscing. Sed lacinia tortor in mollis auctor. Proin sit amet est ante. Sed fermentum arcu ut arcu ultricies, quis luctus odio vehicula. Duis tincidunt elementum lacus quis cursus. Integer porta sit amet purus et viverra. Nulla quis sollicitudin urna. Pellentesque et nunc semper, dapibus massa ac, scelerisque ipsum. In tempus massa et tortor mattis, sit amet laoreet neque accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce euismod non massa at sagittis.

Vestibulum pulvinar purus odio. Vestibulum non iaculis metus. Maecenas at aliquam leo, eu commodo dui. In id ullamcorper metus, in convallis massa. Donec a ante nec risus vehicula suscipit sit amet a dui. Etiam quam enim, posuere et tempor vitae, accumsan vel risus. Vivamus a arcu tortor. Morbi auctor placerat massa convallis sagittis. Vivamus accumsan vulputate rhoncus. Phasellus mattis orci non luctus interdum. Praesent eu feugiat mi. Phasellus vitae elementum nunc. Aliquam luctus aliquam tellus, quis commodo ipsum molestie vel. Cras ut dignissim erat.

Aenean luctus porta enim eu feugiat. Mauris quis tristique massa, id commodo risus. Morbi consectetur, magna nec molestie tincidunt, libero nunc volutpat nulla, quis feugiat metus leo quis enim. Proin varius, turpis id rhoncus mattis, dui magna fringilla nisi, nec blandit nisl arcu ac tortor. Proin est nisi, tempor sit amet porta ac, cursus sit amet est. Praesent suscipit, nibh non malesuada aliquet, dui turpis sagittis magna, nec facilisis metus magna ut turpis. Fusce sit amet massa at mi euismod elementum sit amet id massa. Duis nec magna vitae arcu consequat tempus. Etiam non pellentesque libero. Cras aliquet convallis adipiscing. Aliquam dictum viverra sem nec tempus. Nulla odio justo, ornare ut velit vel, commodo venenatis libero. Curabitur in tincidunt elit. Ut ac luctus risus, quis interdum neque. Sed quis nulla id erat gravida pretium sit amet eget odio.

Curabitur egestas a mi eget sollicitudin. Ut interdum dictum augue lobortis consequat. Aliquam congue pharetra rhoncus. Ut nec tortor eget nunc vestibulum venenatis id quis nibh. Nullam at dui consequat, aliquet odio porttitor, convallis sapien. In bibendum ipsum non elementum euismod. Maecenas eu justo a diam mollis placerat ac sit amet mauris. Phasellus id aliquam ligula, et tristique est. Etiam at arcu pretium, accumsan odio eu, vestibulum tellus. Etiam dapibus laoreet volutpat. Sed et urna ipsum. Nulla ultrices quam sem, eu eleifend purus iaculis a. Nunc sit amet congue mauris.

Sed euismod est urna. Aliquam lacinia nulla et mi tempus porta. Aliquam varius, nulla nec vestibulum lobortis, urna ligula gravida est, non sollicitudin lorem dolor ac enim. Vivamus non porta velit. Aenean ut bibendum nunc. Sed non lectus dapibus, mattis nisl condimentum, placerat nibh. Nulla tempus molestie laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet magna id erat auctor vulputate non non odio. Morbi at ipsum condimentum, commodo velit tincidunt, iaculis est. In ultrices, quam hendrerit luctus suscipit, urna odio ornare risus, sed laoreet odio libero vitae ipsum. In quis venenatis lacus. Mauris elementum risus eget justo cursus viverra.
      </section>
      <section data-panel="third"><h1>test</h1><br><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat erat at rhoncus porta. Vestibulum fringilla viverra laoreet. Ut vel nunc adipiscing, consequat mauris eget, aliquet leo. Nunc viverra posuere elit, ut hendrerit massa dignissim vitae. Ut euismod quam ut sapien sagittis, ac euismod libero rutrum. Sed at justo felis. Proin condimentum tortor a erat laoreet, quis adipiscing velit elementum. Pellentesque egestas sem a ante aliquet, in semper eros venenatis. Mauris faucibus orci bibendum libero aliquam rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc fermentum dolor vel nisi rhoncus, ultrices tincidunt nisi vehicula. Nulla eros nibh, interdum quis tellus nec, convallis ullamcorper sapien. Pellentesque adipiscing gravida suscipit.

Proin vitae nisi quis lectus tristique auctor. Nam tristique sapien sit amet odio faucibus adipiscing. Sed lacinia tortor in mollis auctor. Proin sit amet est ante. Sed fermentum arcu ut arcu ultricies, quis luctus odio vehicula. Duis tincidunt elementum lacus quis cursus. Integer porta sit amet purus et viverra. Nulla quis sollicitudin urna. Pellentesque et nunc semper, dapibus massa ac, scelerisque ipsum. In tempus massa et tortor mattis, sit amet laoreet neque accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce euismod non massa at sagittis.

Vestibulum pulvinar purus odio. Vestibulum non iaculis metus. Maecenas at aliquam leo, eu commodo dui. In id ullamcorper metus, in convallis massa. Donec a ante nec risus vehicula suscipit sit amet a dui. Etiam quam enim, posuere et tempor vitae, accumsan vel risus. Vivamus a arcu tortor. Morbi auctor placerat massa convallis sagittis. Vivamus accumsan vulputate rhoncus. Phasellus mattis orci non luctus interdum. Praesent eu feugiat mi. Phasellus vitae elementum nunc. Aliquam luctus aliquam tellus, quis commodo ipsum molestie vel. Cras ut dignissim erat.

Aenean luctus porta enim eu feugiat. Mauris quis tristique massa, id commodo risus. Morbi consectetur, magna nec molestie tincidunt, libero nunc volutpat nulla, quis feugiat metus leo quis enim. Proin varius, turpis id rhoncus mattis, dui magna fringilla nisi, nec blandit nisl arcu ac tortor. Proin est nisi, tempor sit amet porta ac, cursus sit amet est. Praesent suscipit, nibh non malesuada aliquet, dui turpis sagittis magna, nec facilisis metus magna ut turpis. Fusce sit amet massa at mi euismod elementum sit amet id massa. Duis nec magna vitae arcu consequat tempus. Etiam non pellentesque libero. Cras aliquet convallis adipiscing. Aliquam dictum viverra sem nec tempus. Nulla odio justo, ornare ut velit vel, commodo venenatis libero. Curabitur in tincidunt elit. Ut ac luctus risus, quis interdum neque. Sed quis nulla id erat gravida pretium sit amet eget odio.

Curabitur egestas a mi eget sollicitudin. Ut interdum dictum augue lobortis consequat. Aliquam congue pharetra rhoncus. Ut nec tortor eget nunc vestibulum venenatis id quis nibh. Nullam at dui consequat, aliquet odio porttitor, convallis sapien. In bibendum ipsum non elementum euismod. Maecenas eu justo a diam mollis placerat ac sit amet mauris. Phasellus id aliquam ligula, et tristique est. Etiam at arcu pretium, accumsan odio eu, vestibulum tellus. Etiam dapibus laoreet volutpat. Sed et urna ipsum. Nulla ultrices quam sem, eu eleifend purus iaculis a. Nunc sit amet congue mauris.

      </section>
    </div>
    <script>
  var options = {
    $menu: true,
    menuSelector: 'a',
    panelSelector: 'section',
    namespace: '.panelSnap',
    onSnapStart: function(){},
    onSnapFinish: function(){},
    directionThreshold: 20,
    slideSpeed: 200
  };

  $('.panel_container').panelSnap(options);
</script>
  </body>
```

The js is located here; https://github.com/guidobouman/jquery-panelsnap/blob/master/jquery.panelSnap.js

Basically I just copied the demo file with the menu attached. I added the options script part, enabled the menu. I made sure all the names are what they are supposed to be and created some lipsum so there is actual room to scroll to.

My first note was that the demo says the menu should go to '/first', I changed this to '#first', because the / does not indicate an anchor point.

So except for that point I cannot find what is wrong with my code, I hope someone can give me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take out the extra script tag you have in the bottom and put the head script tag in it's place. Then set the panel container style to `position: absolute` and `overflow: scroll`.

That should be enough to get it working. However, depending on the size of your screen it may not work well because the height of each panel is specified in pixels. Changing the panel container and section height to 100% worked much better for me. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/5Va8G/4/), and here's what my css looked like after these changes:

```
.panel_container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your script from :

```
  var options = {
    $menu: $('header .menu')
  };

  $('.panel_container').panelSnap(options);
```

To be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var options = {
        $menu: $('header .menu')
      };

      $('.panel_container').panelSnap(options);
});
```

See [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for why the `$(document).ready();` wrapper is required.

Comment: Did not solve the whole problem but this certainly helped, thanks for the explanation too :)

Comment: You may also need to wrap the second part of your script in the wrapper also. (i.e. the script at the end of the body tag)

Comment: Wrapping the second part did not help but thank you for the suggestion.